# "The installation does not satisfy the requirements list below." in Eclipse - what does it mean?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-oxygen

Eclipse Oxygen prompted me about software update - it wanted to update Mylyn WikiText.
But I had a problem with this - error message was something about artifact cannot be found in any repository. After trying to resolve it, I just thought that I try to remove this plugin (not sure what it is, don't care about it).

But when I start Eclipse after that, it says:
**The installation does not satisfy the requirements list below.** - on the list is of course mylyn.wikitext_feature.

What does it mean? What should I do with it?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I only recently switched to Oxygen and I'm experiencing a similar behavior. In my case I intentionally started uninstalling everything I didn't want from the J2EE Eclipse distribution.

This is a new feature coming with the Oomph update manager. The popup lets you know that the Eclipse J2EE distribution requires these packages. I need to figure out where these required features are specified but I can tell immediately that there shouldn't be any broken functionality - features that depend on the uninstalled features should have been removed during uninstallation of the packages - in your case mylyn WikiText.

I personally chose to switch my installation to the Java Standard profile so that I don't get bugged by any features missing from the EE profile. I went to main menu -> *Navigate* -> *Open Setup* -> *Installation* then changed to Oxygen (EE developers) to Oxygen (Java developers) in the properties.

[image]

You can find more information starting from this thread: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=1082235

In your case I believe the proper action is either of the following:

- Resolve the missing dependencies for Mylyn WikiText.
- Select the *Remember my decision* checkbox and click *Skip*. You can undo the option later by going to the Oomph settings under *Window* -> *Preferences...*